# Android script to move files?

Tags: android, sh

I'm trying to create a simple script that will move files around on my Nexus 7. It is stock Android 4.2.2. What I have done is I have tried to create a `test.sh` script with the following contents:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

su
cp -r /folder/* /mnt/sdcard/dcim/camera
```

Upon trying to run this script from the command line using `sh ./test.sh`, I get the following errors:

```
: not foundsh[2]:
: not foundsh[3]: su
cp: /folder/*: Permission denied
```

I have placed `test.sh` at the root folder of my Nexus 7 and there is definitely a `/system/bin` folder that has `sh` inside of it. The `cp` command also works properly after `su` is entered, so the problem is definitely getting the script to run correctly. Can anyone help me troubleshoot what may be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Your first line should start with `#!` rather than `*!`, for a start.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo when I was making my post. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `test.sh` to this did the trick:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su -c 'cp -r /folder/* /mnt/sdcard/dcim/camera';
```

It seems that `su` opening a new shell was troublesome for passing the other commands and a line break in the `test.sh` script was causing issues as well.

Comment: what is the function of su? my script results in that message: "su: not found"

Comment: EDIT: superuser app? does it mean I have to root my device?